# Get URL From Browser using Winui 3 in Desktop Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, desktop-application, winui-3

I am creating a desktop application where I need to fetch the urls from different browsers in my desktop application while I am using WinUI 3. In .net core we use `System.windows.Automation` but here we have the `Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Automation` but didn't know how to retrieve the urls.

Comment: Could you please post the code you are using in .Net Core to retrieve urls?

Comment: i have no any sourcec code because i don't know how i can get URLs from different browsers in my desktop application